Closed form for integer coefficients using Stirling numbers of the first kind

Let $s(n,k)$ be the Stirling numbers of the first kind. Here
$$
(x)_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} s(n,k)x^k.
$$
where $(x)_n$ is the falling factorial such that
$$
(x)_n = x(x-1)(x-2)\dotsc(x-n+1).
$$
Let $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ be A000120 (i.e., number of ones in the binary expansion of $n$). Here
$$
\operatorname{wt}(2n+1) = \operatorname{wt}(n) + 1, \\
\operatorname{wt}(2n) = \operatorname{wt}(n), \\
\operatorname{wt}(0) = 0.
$$
Let $a(n)$ be A329369. Here
$$
a(2^m(2k+1)) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{m} \binom{m+1}{j}a(2^jk), \\
a(0) = 1.
$$
Let $b(n)$ be A341392. Here
$$
b(2n+1) = b(n), \\
b(2n) = (1 + \operatorname{wt}(n))b(n), \\
b(0) = 1.
$$
Let $T(n,k)$ be an integer coefficients such that
$$
T(2n+1,k) = T(n,k) + (\operatorname{wt}(n)-k+3)T(n,k-1), \\
T(2n,k) = (\operatorname{wt}(n)-k+2)T(2n+1,k), \\
T(n, 1) = b(n).
$$
Here we consider that $T(0,k) = 0$ for $k>1$ and $T(n,k) = 0$ for $k<1$.

I conjecture that
$$
T(k,\operatorname{wt}(k)-m+1) = \frac{1}{((m+1)!)^2}\sum\limits_{j=2}^{m+2}a(2^{j-2}(2k+1))s(m+2,j).
$$
Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:
a(n) = if(n==0, 1, my(A = tr(n), B = n >> (A+1)); sum(j=0, A, binomial(A+1, j)*a(B<<j)))
b(n) = my(k=if(n, logint(n, 2)), s=1); prod(i=0, k, s+=bittest(n, k-i))/(1+hammingweight(n))!
row1(n) = if(n==0, [1], my(A = logint(n,2)+1, B, C, t = n, v1, v2, v3); v1 = vector(A, i, 0); v1[1] = 1; v2 = Vecrev(vector(A-1, i, b(t\=2))); v3 = vector(hammingweight(n)+1, i, 0); v3[1] = b(n); for(i=1, #v3-1, B = -i+2; if(i>1, v1[i-1] = 0); for(j=2, A, C = bittest(n, A-j); B += C; v1[j] = v1[j-1] + (B+!C)*v2[j-1]; if(!C, v1[j] *= B)); v2 = v1; v3[i+1] = v1[A]); v3)
row2(n) = my(v1); v1 = Vecrev(vector(hammingweight(n)+1, i, i--; sum(j=2, i+2, a(2^(j-2)*(2*n+1))*stirling(i+2, j, 1))/((i+1)!)^2))
test(n) = row1(n) == row2(n)

Is there a way to prove it?
